# Get controller name in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In my app I am creating a dynamic menu. The menu is populated depending upon the controller it is called for. For example in one of my Controller name is Organization. To populate the menu for it I call this

```
@Html.Action("Menu","Site", new { calledForController = "Organization", oId = @Model.Id })
```

Everything is working nice and smooth but the issue I am experiencing as I am having more views is that I have to put the above line in every view. What I am looking for is a way to get the current controller and action name from the route data so that I don't have to call this on every view.

The ideal solution would be to write something like this

```
@Html.Action("Menu","Site")
```

in my _Layout.cshtml and then in the menu controller populate menu list depending upon where it was called from.

If I write

```
this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

in my Menu action of Site controller I am always getting Site as my controller name. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched and found this as an appropriate solution for me, to get the Route data use this

```
var routeValues = HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;

if (routeValues.ContainsKey("id"))
   oId = (String)routeValues["id"];
```

This way in my _Layout.cshtml I can write this

```
@Html.Action("Menu","Site")
```

And now I don't have to pass in extra called for controller again and again.